# Laplace Transform - Differentiation in Time property demonstration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms, convergence

I have a signal

```
x[t_]=t/3 Exp[-3t] UnitStep[t]
```

and the laplace transform as

```
X[s_]=Integrate[x[t]Exp[-s t],{t,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

**I am trying to take the derivative of x[t] and applying a Laplace transform on that to show that it equals sX[s]**

This is how I take the derivative: `dx[t_]=D[x[t],t]`
and this is how I apply the transform to it: `X0[s_] = Integrate[x'[t] Exp[-s t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]`
Something keeps going wrong with this last line of code and integration bit.

I also want to show that the ROC for `sX(s)` is AT LEAST R. I believe I might've just picked the wrong signal for it so if any of you have any suggestions on how to make this demonstration work, I am all ears!

Thank you sooo much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Laplace Transform function:

```
x[t_] := t/3 Exp[-3 t] UnitStep[t];
eqn1 = LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]
eqn2 = LaplaceTransform[D[x[t], t], t, s]
```

You can verify the derivative property using:

```
FullSimplify[s eqn1] == FullSimplify[eqn2]
True
```

Of course it's also true in general:

```
LaplaceTransform[D[z[t], t], t, s]
```

which returns

```
s LaplaceTransform[z[t], t, s] - z[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great! I was just wondering, how would I go about plotting eqn1 and eqn2 and the Laplace transforms in general?

Comment: `UnitStep` is superfluous since `LaplaceTransform[t/3 Exp[-3 t], t, s]` produces the same result as `LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]`.